# typealias as emoji with invalid expression

Tags: swift

i want to declare a new `typealias` as follows:

```
typealias  = as?
```

[image]

i know it look stupid but in `Hebrew` Goat pronounced like 'as'
so the goal is to use  instead of as? where `optional binding` happens.

i get compiler error when implementing like that. 
when i try to implement as operator i get error that the emoji considered identifier and not operator.

how can i achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `typealias` is for giving a type another name. You can't use `typealias` to give Swift keywords another name.

In other words, you can't do what you are trying to do.

And to be clear, the issue has nothing to do with the use of an Emoji.

Comment: thanks! got any ideas to implement with other language features?

Comment: @orazran I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: instead of using typealias to replace the value of the emoji with the as? expression. can i achieve it in a different way?

Comment: No. You can't replace Swift keywords.